# set variable in a different view in WPF with MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, model

I would like to bring up a loader in a view that is always visible on the screen , while the user is moving between different view .
footer I added the loader , and I'd do it through variable appear and disappear through my model instantiated .
But it does not work. In debug model sect true / false value correctly the model , but does not consider the footer . Some help ? Or by event ? it's possible ?

Footer XAML

```
<StackPanel  DataContext="{StaticResource vmp}" Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="40" Background="#eeeeee">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="FooterRegion" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

            <TextBlock Text="eStart Enterprise 2.13.15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" Margin="25,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            <!-- my loader is progressbar here, default is false -->
            <ProgressBar Width="200" Margin="885, 0, 0, 0" Visibility="{Binding Path=model.Loader, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsIndeterminate="True" Value="100" />
        </StackPanel>
```

myViewModel.cs (I would call the view model to another xaml variable to set the true progressbar
):

```
class ReadAndPrintFromDevice : ICommand
             {

                 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

                 public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
                 {
                     return true;
                 }

                 public async void Execute(object parameter)
                 {
                     //this don't work
                     modelViewModel.getInstance().Loader = true;
                     //other code
                 }
}
```

how can I fix it so that all I view on or off the loader always on that variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use prism, so you can use IEventAggregator.

Create DataModel for event

```
public class ChangeLoaderEventDataModel
{
}
```

Create event

```
public class ChangeLoaderEvent: PubSubEvent<ChangeLoaderEventDataModel>
{
}
```

Next subscribe on event in control, which contains loader

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeLoaderEvent>().Subscribe(ShowLoaderMethod);
```

After that you can fire event when and where you need it

```
 _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeLoaderEvent>().Publish(new ChangeLoaderEventDataModel());
```